# How to fix "Could not find a package configuration file ..." error in CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I have been working on a project which uses [rplidar_sdk](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_sdk) and in the beginning, I was facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64978368/10358768) problem:

> How can I link locally installed SDK's static library in my C++ project?
>
> Basically, the SDK generates the library in its local directory, and in its `Makefile`, it does not have `install` rules. I mean I can run `make` but after that, if I run `sudo make install` then it gives `make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.` error.

So, with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64978601/10358768) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044763/10358768) answer, I was able to build my local project. So far so good.

However, the main problem is that I have to hard-code the RPLidar SDK path in `CMakeLists.txt` of my repo. Now, whenever someone else in my team starts working on that repo (which is quite obvious) then he/she has to update the `CMakeLists.txt` first. This is not a good idea/practice!

To fix this, I updated the [`Makefile`](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_sdk/blob/master/sdk/Makefile) of RPLidar SDK as follow:

```
.
.
.

RPLIDAR_RELEASE_LIB := $(HOME_TREE)/output/Linux/Release/librplidar_sdk.a

install: $(RPLIDAR_RELEASE_LIB)
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/rplidar/Release/
    install -m 644 $(RPLIDAR_RELEASE_LIB) $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/rplidar/Release/


RPLIDAR_DEBUG_LIB := $(HOME_TREE)/output/Linux/Debug/librplidar_sdk.a

install: $(RPLIDAR_DEBUG_LIB)
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/rplidar/Debug/
    install -m 644 $(RPLIDAR_DEBUG_LIB) $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/lib/rplidar/Debug/


RPLIDAR_HEADERS := $(HOME_TREE)/sdk/include

install: $(RPLIDAR_HEADERS)
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/include/rplidar/
    cp -r $(RPLIDAR_HEADERS)/* $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/include/rplidar/

RPLIDAR_HEADERS_HAL := $(HOME_TREE)/sdk/src/hal

install: $(RPLIDAR_HEADERS_HAL)
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/include/rplidar/
    cp -r $(RPLIDAR_HEADERS_HAL) $(DESTDIR)/usr/local/include/rplidar/
```

Due to this update, now, I can run `sudo make install` which basically copies the header files of RPLidar SDK from the local directory to `/usr/local/rplidar/` directory. It also copies the lib file to `/usr/local/lib/rplidar/<Debug> or <Release>/` directory.

Now, in my local project, I updated the `CMakeLists.txt` to as follow:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(<project_name>)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -pthread)

include_directories(include)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp src/another_src_file.cpp)

find_package(rplidar REQUIRED)
include_directories(${rplidar_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${rplidar_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${rplidar_LIBRARY})
```

However, upon running `cmake ..` command, I'm getting this error:

```
.
.
.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findrplidar.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "rplidar", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rplidar" with any
  of the following names:

    rplidarConfig.cmake
    rplidar-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rplidar" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "rplidar_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "rplidar" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

As far as I know, RPLidar SDK does not have `rplidarConfig.cmake` or `rplidar-config.cmake` file.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I couldn't think of a better title. If someone can come up with a more appropriate title then please update it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rants from my soul:

It sucks when you have to use any library `foo` when the author fails to provide a `foo-config.cmake` for you to use easily by invoking `find_package(foo)`. It's absolutely outrageous when a reasonably modern project still uses hand written Makefiles as its build system. I myself is stuck with a much worse constructed SDK than yours right now.

---

Short answer:

Since the author of the SDK fails to provide a config file to support your cmake usage, if you still insists on invoking `find_package` on the library (and you should!), you are required to write your own `Module` file to clean up their mess. (Yeah, you are doing the work for the library authors).

To truly achieve cross platform usage, you should write a `Findrplidar.cmake` module file to find the libraries for you.

To write a reasonable module file, you would most likely use API `find_path` for header files and `find_library` for libs. You should check out its docs and try using them, and maybe Google a few tutorials.

Here is my version of `Findglog.cmake` for your reference. (glog authors have updated [their code](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/glog-config.cmake.in) and supports `Config` mode. Unfortunately, Ubuntu build doesn't use it, so I still have to write my own file)

```
find_path(glog_INCLUDE_DIR glog/logging.h)
message(STATUS "glog header found at: ${glog_INCLUDE_DIR}")

find_library(glog_LIB glog)
message(STATUS "libglog found at: ${glog_LIB}")

mark_as_advanced(glog_INCLUDE_DIR glog_LIB)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(glog REQUIRED_VARS
  glog_INCLUDE_DIR
  glog_LIB
  )

if(glog_FOUND AND NOT TARGET glog::glog)
  add_library(glog::glog SHARED IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(glog::glog PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES "CXX"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${glog_LIB}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
      "${glog_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    )
endif()
```

And you can use it like this:

```
find_package(glog)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE glog::glog)
```

---

Long answer:

The history of developers using cmake is an absolute nightmare. The internet is filled with bad practice/examples of how not to use cmake in your project, including the old official cmake tutorial (which still might be there). Mostly because no one really gives a **** (If I can build my project, who cares if it's cross platform). Another valid reason is that cmake documentations are really daunting to beginners.

This is why I am writing my own answer here, lest you get misguided by Googling elsewhere.

The nightmare is no more. The wait has ended. "The Messiah" of cmake ([source](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/)) is come. He bringeth hope to asm/C/C++/CUDA projects written in 2020 and on. Here is [The Word](https://youtu.be/bsXLMQ6WgIk).

The link above points to the only way how cmake projects should be written and truly achieve cross platform once and for all. Note the material is not easy at all to follow for beginners. I myself spent an entire week to fully grasp what was covered in The Word, when I had become somewhat familiar with cmake concepts at the time (but lost in my old sinful ways).

The so-called "long answer" is actually shorter. It's just a pointer to the real answer. Good luck reading the Word. Embrace the Word, for anything against that is pure heresy.

---

#### Response of comment 1-5:

Good questions. A lot of those can be obtained from the Word. But the word is better digested when you become more familiar with CMake. Let me answer them in decreasing of relevance to your problem at hand.

For the ease of discussion, I'll just use libfoo as an example.

Let's say you always wants to use libfoo like this:

```
find_package(foo)
target_link_libraries(your_exe ... foo::foo)
```

Pretend foo is installed at the following location:

```
- /home/dev/libfoo-dev/
  - include
    - foo
      - foo.h
      - bar.h
      - ...
  - lib
    - libfoo.so
  - share
    - foo/foo-config.cmake   # This may or may not exist. See discussion.
```

---

Q: Only one `.h` file. Why?

A: Because in the case of `libfoo` (also true for `glog`), only one search of header location is necessary. Just like the example from `libfoo`,
where `foo/foo.h` and `foo/bar.h` are at the same location. So their output of `find_path` would be the same: `/home/dev/libfoo-dev/include`.

---

Q: Why I'm getting `NOTFOUND` for my headers and libs?

A: The function `find_path` and `find_library` only search locations specify in the documentations. By default they search system locations,
like `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` respectively. Refer to the official docs for details on system locations. In the case of `libfoo`, however,
they reside in `/home/dev/libfoo-dev`. So you must specify these locations in cmake variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. It's a `;` seperated string.
One would do `cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/dev/libfoo-dev;/more/path/for/other/libs/;...;/even/more/path" ....` on the command line.

One very important note: unlike Unix command `find`, `find_path` will only search specific paths inside `/home/dev/libfoo-dev`, not all the way down:
`include` (usually also `include/{arch}` where {arch} is sth like `x86_64-linux-gnu` for x86 Linux) for `find_path`; `lib` variant for `find_library`,
respectively. Unusual locations would require passing in more arguments, which is uncommon and most likely unnecessary.

For this very reason, for `libfoo`, calling `find_path(... foo.h ...)` is undesired. One would want `find_path(... foo/foo.h ...)`. Refer to the docs
for more details. You can also try out yourself.

Also for this reason, it is desirable to organize libraries in the usual `bin include lib share` quad on Unix-like systems. I'm not familiar with Windows.

---

Q: `Debug` & `Release`

A: There are several options. The easiest one might be:

- Prepare rplidar debug and release build in two different folders, `/path/to/debug` & `/path/to/release` for instance
- Passing to `Debug` & `Release` build respectively (`cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/path/to/debugORrelease" ....`)

There are definitely others ways, but perhaps requires special care in your `Findrplidar.cmake` script (maybe some `if` statements).

---

Q: Why `glog::glog` rather than `glog`?

A: It's just modern cmake practice, with small benefits. Not important right now. Refer to the Word if you are interested.

---

Q: You mentioned that you are writing `rplidarConfig.cmake`. Instead you should rename the file to `Findrplidar.cmake`.

A: CMake philosophy is as such:

- Library authors should write `foo-config.cmake` or `fooConfig.cmake`
- When they fail to provide one, it sucks. And according to the Messiah, it should be reported as a bug.
- In this case, you as library user, should write `Findfoo.cmake` by guessing how to describe the dependencies for libfoo. For simple libraries, this is not so bad. For complex ones, like Boost, this sucks!

A few side note on this topic:

- Note how `Findfoo.cmake` is written by library users, from guessing.
- This is insane! Users shouldn't do this. This is the authors' fault, to put their users in this uncomfortable situation.
- A `foo-config.cmake` file is extremely easy to write for authors of libfoo, IF they follow the Word exactly.
- Extremely easy for the authors in the sense that: cmake can take care of everything. It will generate scripts automatically for the authors to use in their `foo-config.cmake` file.
- Guaranteed to be cross-platform and easy to use by the users, thanks to cmake.
- However, the reality sucks. Now you have to write `Findfoo.cmake`

---

Q: Why only `find_package` & `target_link_libraries`?

A: This is what the Word says. It's therefore good practice. Why the Word says so is something you have to find out yourself.
It's not possible for me to explain the gist of the Word in this answer, nor would it be convincing to you. I would just say the following:

It's very easy to write spaghetti CMakeLists that are next to impossible to maintain. The spirit of the Word helps you avoid that by
forcing you to carefully think about:

- library structure: public vs private headers, for example. This makes you think about what to include in your headers and public APIs.
- build specification: what is necessary to build a library you write (what to include; what to link)
- usage requirement: what is necessary for others to use a library you write (what to include; what to link)
- dependencies: what is the relationship of the library you write & its dependencies
- Maybe more

If you think about it, these aspects are crucial to writing a cross-platform and maintainable library.
`include_directories`, `link_directories` and `add_definitions` are all very bad practice
(according to lots of sources, including the official documentations of these APIs). Bad practice tends to obscure the aspects above,
and causes problems later on when everything gets integrate together as a whole. E.g. `include_directories` will add `-I` to compiler for every
target written in the directory of that `CMakeLists.txt`. Read this sentence a few times and Spock will tell you it's illogical.

Don't worry. It's okay for now to use them when you are not familiar with the Word (Why else would this be in the last section). Once you know the Word, refactor your CMakeLists when you have time. Bad practice might cause problem later on, when your project becomes more complex. (In my professional experience, 5 very small groups of people is enough to cause a nightmare. By nightmare I mean hard code everything in CMakeLists; Create a git branch for every single different platform/device/environment; Fixing a bug meaning to cherry-pick one commit to each branch. I've been there before knowing the Word.)

The practice of the Word very well utilize the philosophy of modern CMake, to encapsulate build specifications and usage requirements inside
CMake targets. So when `target_link_libraries` is called, these properties gets propagated properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response. I really appreciate that. Also, sorry for the late reply from my end. However, I'm still not that much experienced with CMake. I tried to write `rplidarConfig.cmake` with the help of your `CMake`. However, I have so much confusion: 1. in your `find_path` command, there is only one `.h` file. What if there is more than one header file along with the subdirectory? Because upon running `cmake ..` in my local project, I'm getting `-- rplidar headers found at: rplidar_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- librplidar found at: rplidar_LIB-NOTFOUND`

Comment: 2. In `CMake`, generally, we write `find_package`, `include_directories`, `link_directories`, `add_definitions`, and `target_link_libraries`. But you are suggesting to write only `find_package` & `targe_link_libraries`! Why? 3. Why we are doing `glog::glog` rather than just `glog` 4. What if I have different libraries for `Debug` & `Release`?

I haven't got a chance to thoroughly go through the links, you shared. But, sure, I'll do it. So, if you think that after thoroughly going through it would answer my questions then please ignore them.

Comment: 5. Last question: right now, as a workaround, in my `CMakeLists`, I have just added the following three lines: `include_directories(/usr/local/include/rplidar/)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} debug /usr/local/lib/rplidar/Debug/librplidar_sdk.a)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} optimized /usr/local/lib/rplidar/Release/librplidar_sdk.a)` and it works without any errors or warnings. But is it a bad practice?  Because, I can't use `find_package` command as well as `${rplidar_INCLUDE_DIR}` or `${rplidar_LIB}`!
   Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Milan Updated my answer. See the bottom part.

Comment: What do I do with this `Findglog.cmake` file? I have a project I'd like to  build: https://github.com/fbdtemme/bencode , I run `cmake cmakelists.txt`, it uses fmt library and tries to use it with `find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)`, I then get a `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fmt" with any of the following names: fmtConfig.cmake, fmt-config.cmake` error. How do I use the library then? How do the original authors manage to use the library with `find_package`, if fmt doesn't provide the necessary config file and they don't have this file in the repo?

Comment: Do I need to clone every project it references manually, add this `Findglog.cmake` file for each project with respective paths to all files, and then what? I still don't understand how to build the project I'd like to build.

Comment: @KulaGGin fmt's authors have already properly handled cmake, thus `find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)` uses CONFIG mode. `MODULE` mode `findXXX.cmake` is not the answer here. Hard to describe details in comment. Feel free to open a new question with more details and then ping me. Comments are really not a good way to solve a problem. Should be a separate question instead. You might be helping someone else in the future. Search info about `Config` mode first if you are worried about asking dup questions.

Comment: @TerryTsao can you please look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737917/configuration-file-for-the-vcpkg