# Configuration file for the vcpkg

Tags: c, cmake, vcpkg

As an author of a library, what configuration do I need to provide to make it easy for the consumers to install the library.

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(mylib C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_library(mylib src/foo.c src/bar.c)
target_compile_features(mylib PRIVATE c_std_11)

target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# Config
configure_package_config_file(build/config.cmake
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config.cmake # cmake-build-debug/
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME} NO_SET_AND_CHECK_MACRO) # share/

# Version
write_basic_package_version_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config-version.cmake
        VERSION 1.0.0
        COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

# Install Config & Version
install(FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config.cmake # cmake-build-debug/
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config-version.cmake # cmake_build-debug/
        DESTINATION
        ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}) # share/

# Create export set to enable import in other CMake Projects
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-targets # create export set
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # lib/
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # lib/
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} # include/
)
# Install Export Set
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-targets
        NAMESPACE mylib::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${PROJECT_NAME})

# Install Headers
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}) # include/
```

### My config.cmake

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mylib-targets.cmake)

check_required_components(mylib)
```

Please review and advise on what needs to be changed for the config or the CMakeLists file, for a seamless consumer experience.

## Edit Consumer

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(consumer C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(consumer main.c)

find_package(mylib CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(consumer PRIVATE mylib::mylib)
```

---

## Directory structure

```
mylib/
|-- CMakeLists.txt (top-level)
|-- src/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- foo.c
|   |-- bar.c
|-- example/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- example1.c
|   |-- example2.c
```

### example/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(example1 example1.c)
target_link_libraries(example1 PRIVATE mylib)
add_test(NAME TestExample1 COMMAND example1)

add_executable(example2 example2.c)
target_link_libraries(example2 PRIVATE mylib)
add_test(NAME TestExample2 COMMAND example2)
```

Comment: A bit confused about some details in your post. 1. Why is there `mylib-config.cmake` and `mylibConfig.cmake` installed at the same time? In theory either one should suffice for your consumer. 2. In your attempt 1, should the `find_dependency` line be `nanojsonc` instead of `mylib`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @TerryTsao my apologies for the typos, Since I have posted, I have been learning and progressed so you will some changes in the code. Please have another look with a fresh perspective for effectiveness and code articulation and if I did it right.

Comment: I want it to be the shortest possible implementation and as a template for my future libraries (very similar to this one), so at one point I tried to get rid of configuration but seems like `find_package` requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've done an excellent job already. It's guaranteed to be clean and x-platform.

One thing you haven't done according to [Daniel Pfeifer's awesome presentation](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017/blob/master/05-19-2017_friday/effective_cmake__daniel_pfeifer__cppnow_05-19-2017.pdf):

> When you export Foo in namespace Foo::,
> also create an alias Foo::Foo.
>
> add_library(Foo::Foo ALIAS Foo)

This way, when you and your consumer would like to use your lib directly from SOURCE CODE, they can still use in the canonical form with namespace:

```
find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
target_link_library(... PRIVATE mylib::mylib)
```

provided they override `find_package` API like page 34 from the pdf above, sth like this:

```
### NOTE!!! Hand written && NOT tested
set(as_subproj mylib)

macro(find_package)
    if(NOT "${ARG0}" IN_LIST as_subproj)
        _find_package(${ARGV})
    else()
        add_subdirectory(${ARG0})
    endif()
endmacro()
```

Comment: Great, a follow up question. Can there be nested independent projects in a CMake project, for instance, my use case is having example of the library, a compilable project linked to the main library, how do we do that?

Comment: @AppDeveloper I'm sure there is a way to handle this nicely. Perhaps you could elaborate on some more details, for instance the directory structure of your project.

Comment: I have edited with directory structure.

Comment: I'm running my examples as test, since I don't know any better. I wanted to assure that even my examples are working. So that's why I was wondering if there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: @AppDeveloper I kinda get what you are saying. Nested cmake projects are allowed iirc, but I'm not quite familiar with this use case myself. Not an expert on that. Perhaps you can refer to the doc or some other resource.